# Getting accumulated balance column in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I am trying to build a crystal. I am using sql command to retreive datas from database. Following is my command...

```
SELECT
     sum_id, sum_date, id, sum_accname, sum_description, credit, debit, dep_date, chq_due_date, dp_custname
FROM
     sum_balance
WHERE
    sum_accname = {?ac_name}
and
    sum_date >= {?fromDate}
and
    sum_date <={?toDate}
```

My report is like the image I've attached.
[image]

My problem is how to add the balance column using debit and credit. Balance column should be an accumulated balance column. Data types of debit and credit column in SQL dB are [credit] [decimal](18, 2) & [debit] [decimal](18, 2). Really I am stuck in this place. Can anyone help me with this issue. And the other thing is I am using two parameter to filter date. If I filter the report I need to add an Brough forward balance for the report too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this query for that:

```
SELECT
     s1.sum_id, s1.sum_date, s1.id, s1.sum_accname, s1.sum_description, s1.credit, s1.debit, s1.dep_date, s1.chq_due_date, s1.dp_custname,
     SUM(ISNULL(s2.debit, 0) - ISNULL(s2.credit, 0)) As balance
FROM
     sum_balance s1 LEFT JOIN
     sum_balance s2 ON s1.id >= s2.id 
                   AND s1.sum_id >= s2.sum_id 
                   AND s1.sum_date >= s2.sum_date
WHERE
    s1.sum_accname = {?ac_name}
and
    s1.sum_date >= {?fromDate}
and
    s1.sum_date <={?toDate}
GROUP BY
    s1.sum_id, s1.sum_date, s1.id, s1.sum_accname, s1.sum_description, s1.credit, s1.debit, s1.dep_date, s1.chq_due_date, s1.dp_custname
```

Comment: It's showing a balance column but the balance is wrong, Without taking balance using command is there any ways to try with crystal report formula feild or any other ways

Comment: I used this command and changes a place 

AND s1.sum_id >= s2.sum_id to AND s1.sum_accname >= s2.sum_accname and now its giving correct balance while filtering with acc name.